# Remove text after second <a> tag using Jquery

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to remove the text whatever is present after a particular tag using jquery

My html code is

```
<div class="myclass">
    <a href="#"></a>
    <a href="#"></a>
    Hey I want to delete this text
</div>
```

### Jquery

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   $('.myclass').each(function() {
      // Confused here
      $(this).children(':nth-child(3)').text(''); 
   });
});
```

I guess that there is no 3-rd child in the class. Any ideas would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Can you wrap the text in a div, span or else tag?

Comment: Do you mean you only want the <a> tags and their contents in that div?

Comment: for example <div>Hey I want to delete this text</div>

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.myclass').each(function () {
        // Confused here
        $(this).contents().filter(function () {
            return this.nodeType === 3 && $.trim(this.nodeValue).length;
        }).replaceWith('');
    });
});
```

**[Fiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/S62LM/)**

Comment: Felix, Thank you so much. Can you tell me what exactly this.nodeType does?

Comment: @NizamAli it contains the nodes' type - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node.nodeType

Answer (score 1):

<kbd>[**Fiddle Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/cse_tushar/2tpxS/)</kbd>

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.myclass a:eq(1)')[0].nextSibling.remove();
});
```

---

[:eq() Selector](http://api.jquery.com/eq-selector/)

> Zero-based index of the element to match

`$('.myclass a:eq(1)')` get second `a` tag inside element with class `myclass`

than get it's [.nextSibling](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node.nextSibling) and [.remove()](http://api.jquery.com/remove/)

Answer (score 1):

you can do this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.myclass').find('a:last')[0].nextSibling.remove();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$(".myclass").contents().filter(function(){ return this.nodeType == 3; }).remove();
```

**[Working Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/7Z8eK/)**

Comment: That code would remove all text nodes anywhere in the element, not only the ones after the last link.

Answer (score 0):

```
$('.myClass').html($('.myClass').html().substring(0,$('.myClass').html().lastIndexOf(">")))
```

I also came across similar thread. This might help you as well
[How do I select text nodes with jQuery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/298750/how-do-i-select-text-nodes-with-jquery)